# jquery: how to split data without space

Tags: jquery, split

i have some data `ab-cde0001`. i want to separate it become two part: `ab-cde` and `0001`.
i'm just know to separate data if consist of some space inside it.

how do i do that?

---

```
var barcode;
barCode=$("#model").val();
var data=barCode.split("  ");   //must change this
$("#model").val(data[0]);
$("#serial").val(data[1]);
```

---

i have another idea, but i dont know how to start.

may be i'm just need some script read 4 digits behind the text, then split the choosen one.

Comment: Is the string always in this format, i.e. `xx-xxxNNNN`?

Comment: ya..the format almost same like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have combined the answer before, and then i found the real answer:

```
 var barcode;
 barCode=$("#model").val();
 var data1 = $("#model").val(barCode.substr(0,barCode.length-4));
 var data2 = $("#serial").val(barCode.substr(barCode.length-4,4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone had to provide a regex solution...

```
var str = 'ab-cde0001';

var matches = str.match(/^([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{3})(\d{4})$/);
```

`matches[1]` will have the first part, and `matches[2]` will have the second part.

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kdch/).

Comment: this is use regex..i'm not familiar with this.could you explain your script?

Comment: @klox It matches the portions you require - if you have a `console.log` then you can view the matches by visiting the jsFiddle link.

Comment: could i make a simple way, if i'm just need some script read 4 digits behind the text then split it?

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 6 characters and 4 digits, you can just use the `substring` method to get the two parts:

```
var str = 'ab-cde0001';
var part1 = str.substring(0, 6),
    part2 = str.substring(6, 10);
```

Comment: how to put this split process into my script? i post it into my question.

Comment: @klox: Just replace `str` in the above code with the `barcode` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. s needs to be your string to split. The code splits it so that all numbers from the end will be in t, and everything before the numbers will be in s. Doesn't matter how many digits.

```
var s = 'ab-cde0001';
var t = '';
while ('0123456789'.indexOf(s.substr(s.length-1, 1))!=-1) {
    t = s.substr(s.length-1, 1)+t;
    s = s.substr(0, s.length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always just want to chop off the last 4 digits, it's easy. Presuming your string variable is s:

```
part1 = s.substr(0, s.length-4);
part2 = s.substr(s.length-4, 4);
```

Comment: how to input this into my script? could i split the barcode data use this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var barcode;
barCode = $("#model").val();
$("#model").val( barCode.substring(0, 6) );
$("#serial").val( str.substring(6, 4) );
```